# multithreaded unit test - notify calling thread of event to stop sleeping

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

I wrote a test (NUnit) to test my Amazon SES email sending functionality which should generate a bounce notification in my Amazon SQS queue. I poll this queue in a loop for 1 minute on a new thread to wait and verify the bounce notification.

I'd like to increase the time to a few minutes to ensure I dont miss it. However the response may come within seconds in which case I'd want to just record how long it took and finish the test as there is no point to continue waiting once receipt is verified.

How can I accomplish this threading scenario in a clean way, and by that I mean without polluting MethodInMainApp() with test code. In the main app this should not happen (it should continue polling indefinitely), it should only stop early in test. I should probably pass in the ThreadStart function from both entry points but that doesnt answer the question Im asking.

```
   [Test]
    public async void SendAndLogBounceEmailNotification() 
    {

        Thread bouncesThread = Startup.MethodInMainApp();
        bouncesThread.Start();

        bool success = await _emailService.SendAsync(...);

        Assert.AreEqual(success, true);

        //Sleep this thread for 1 minute while the 
        //bouncesThread polls for bounce notifications
        Thread.Sleep(60000); 
    }


   public static Thread MethodInMainApp()
    {
        ...


        Thread bouncesThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                ReceiveMessageResponse receiveMessageResponse = sqsBouncesClient.ReceiveMessage(bouncesQueueRequest);
                if(receiveMessageResponse.Messages.Count > 0) 
                { 
                     ProcessQueuedBounce(receiveMessageResponse);
                     //done for test
                }                    
            }
        });

        bouncesThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        return bouncesThread;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Monitor class.

Instead of `Thread.Sleep(60000)`, use this:

```
lock (_lockObject)
{
    Monitor.Wait(_lockObject, 60000);
}
```

Then where you want to signal the thread to continue:

```
lock (_lockObject)
{
    Monitor.Pulse(_lockObject);
}
```

Of course this requires adding `static readonly object _lockObject = new object()` somewhere in the class.

I'm not saying that the overall strategy is actually the right approach. Seems like here, it would be better for the unit test method to explicitly call some other method which is doing the work to wait for and validate the response. But the above should address your specific question.

Comment: hey thanks, but Im getting error "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code". I created the lockobject on the test class and pass it into my method as an optional parameter. This way I can ignore it when it's not a test and just do if(lockobject != null) Monitor.Pulse(lockobject); That line throws the error

Comment: As the error message says, you are calling Monitor.Pulse() without first taking the lock on the object. If you want to make it optional, fine. But you still need "lock (lockobject)" before you are allowed to call Monitor.Pulse().